# Load testing for magento application

Tags: magento-1.7, testing

What are the open source tools to load test magento application. If I want to carry out an investigation on load testing issues in magento applications what are the Principles and methodology that I should Follow. Does the Load testing technique differ from other application products?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/), [apache bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html), [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/) to load test your website.

Try increasing the load on your server with these tools. And find the maximum number of clients that your application can handle. Then increase more load to see how more it can take before it breaks.

Comment: simulation and real world traffic are two different things.